# Polchinski, Making a good gauge choice

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

I was reading Polchinski book and there he tries to make a gauge choice to fix the redundacies in the Polyakov action.

In order to make this choice, he fixes $$\tau=X^{+}\tag{1.3.8a}$$ and then he says $f=\gamma_{\sigma\sigma}\left(-\det\gamma\right)^{-1/2}$ transforms as $$f'd\sigma'=fd\sigma \tag{1.3.9},$$ under reparameterizations of $\sigma$ where $\tau$ is left fixed.  I would like to show this last equation, but I couldn't. Can you help me?

Comment: Hint: Write down the transformation law for a metric tensor $\gamma_{ab}$ under a coordinate transformation $(\tau,\sigma)\to (\tau,\sigma^{\prime})$.

Comment: I make that , I got this transformation under the supposition $\sigma'\left(\sigma\right)$. But I would like to know if It's unnecessary this supposition.

Comment: $\gamma'_{\sigma'\sigma'}=\frac{\partial\sigma^{a}}{\partial\sigma'}\frac{\partial\sigma^{b}}{\partial\sigma'}\gamma_{ab}$ . In order to eliminate terms as $\gamma_{\tau\sigma}$ or $\gamma_{\tau\tau}$ . I used the assumption $\sigma'(\sigma)$

Comment: $\uparrow$ You should.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the determinant of the metric behave as a $()_{\sigma\sigma}$ (two lower $\sigma$ indices) under $\sigma$-reparametrizations with $\tau$ held fixed.

$$
\det(\gamma_{ab})=\gamma_{\sigma\sigma}\gamma_{\tau\tau}-\gamma_{\sigma\tau}\gamma_{\sigma\tau}
$$
You can see that from the counting how many $\sigma$ indices there are in each term of the determinant. The square root of it, $\sqrt{\det(\gamma_{ab})}$  will behave as $()_{\sigma}$, just one index. Finally, taking the inverse this will behave as $()^{\sigma}$, just one upper index. Now, $f=\gamma_{\sigma\sigma}(\det(\gamma_{ab}))^{-1/2}$ will behave as $()_{\sigma}$ since $2-1=1$. Knowing that $d\sigma$ behave as $()^{\sigma}$ under $\sigma$-reparametrization you get:

$$
fd\sigma=f'd\sigma'
$$